# Elasticsearchをポート指定せずに使用できるでしょうか？

Tags: centos, elasticsearch

**Elasticsearchを普通のWebアプリケーション(検索エンジン)として使用してみたいのですが、**
・「CentOS Apache」で動作させている「さくらVPS」上に設置する場合、ポート指定せず、普通にアクセスすることは可能でしょうか？

**例えば、下記のようなURLへアクセスしたら、検索画面を表示するようにしたいのですが…**
https://example.com/

**ポート指定は、なぜ必要でしょうか？**
・回避できない？
 http://example.com:9200/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記のいずれかで実現出切ると思います。

1. Apacheを削除して ES を TCP/80で動かす (ES を root で動かす必用あり)
2. Apache からリバースプロキシで Elasticsearch の TCP/9100 に転送する
3. iptable や 上位のネットワーク機器で NAPT を行う

個人的にはリバースプロキシが良さそうに感じます。
リバースプロキシは Apache の設定で 次のようにすればよいでしょう。

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:9200/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9200/
```

Comment: 「2.Apache からリバースプロキシ」を選択した場合について。現在、Apacheでバーチャルホスト設定しているのですが、既存のバーチャルホストは従来通り運用して、特定のバーチャルホストにのみ Apacheでリバースプロキシの設定を行うことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 可能です。バーチャルホストは複数設定出来ますので、そのうち1つで リバースプロキシの設定をすれば 既存の方には影響ないはずです。

Comment: なるほど。 Apacheでリバースプロキシって出来るのですね。大変参考になりました